# InApp Purchase Consumable Server Validation Set Up

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I am using `SwiftyStoreKit` for InApp Purchase Consumable for a tip jar. Everything works for testing but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46039572/4833705) and the comments server side validation isn't necessary but it is suggested. The answer states `"consumables, un-consumables and subscriptions are susceptible to fraudulent attacks. Often though iap crackers or network spoofing. Validating the receipt can mitigate this problem"`.

1- If userA sends me a tip how is it possible for an attacker to intercept that tip and take the money if everything goes through Apple?

2- Do I need to set up a Heroku instance or use something else for the server validation? I can't find anything on it. I would assume I would need to add the server side code in the `success case` below in `if product.needsFinishTransaction { SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction) }` but I don't know how to set up a server from that point on.

```
SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(product, quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in

    switch result {
        case .success(let product):
            // fetch content from your server, then:
            if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }
            print("Purchase Success: \(product.productId)")
        // failed cases ...
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions(atomically: true) { purchases in
        for purchase in purchases {
            switch purchase.transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased, .restored:
                if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                    // Deliver content from server, then:
                    SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                }
            // Unlock content
            case .failed, .purchasing, .deferred:
                break // do nothing
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TipJarVC. The purchase is made in the `collectionView's didSelect item`:

```
var dataSource = [Tip]()
var sharedSecret = appStoreConnectSecretKey

let inAppProductIds = ["com.myCo.myAppName.firstTip", // 0.99
                       "com.myCo.myAppName.secondTip", // 9.99 ]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   getInAppPurchaseAmounts()
}

func getInAppPurchaseAmounts() {

    // show spinner

    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for productId in inAppProductIds {

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([productId]) { [weak self](result) in
            if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
                let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
                print("Product: \(product.localizedDescription), price: \(priceString)")

                let tip = Tip(displayName: product.description,
                              description: product.localizedDescription,
                              productId: productId
                              price: priceString)


                self?.addTipToDataSource(tip)

                if let sharedSecret = self?.sharedSecret {

                    self?.verifyPurchase(with: productId, sharedSecret: sharedSecret)
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()

            } else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
                print("Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
                dispatchGroup.leave()

            } else {
                print("Error: \(String(describing: result.error))")
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global(qos: .background)) { [weak self] in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

            // removeSpinnerAndReloadData()
        }
    }
}

func verifyPurchase(with productId: String, sharedSecret: String) {

    let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: sharedSecret)
    SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let receipt):
            let productId = productId
            // Verify the purchase of Consumable or NonConsumable
            let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifyPurchase(
                productId: productId,
                inReceipt: receipt)

            switch purchaseResult {
            case .purchased(let receiptItem):
                print("\(productId) is purchased: \(receiptItem)")
            case .notPurchased:
                print("The user has never purchased \(productId)")
            }
        case .error(let error):
            print("Receipt verification failed: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? TipCell else { return }
    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    let tip = dataSource[indexPath.item]

    purchaseProduct(with: tip.productId)
}

func purchaseProduct(with productId: String) {

    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([productId]) { result in
        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
            SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(product, quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in

                switch result {
                case .success(let product):
                    // fetch content from your server, then:
                    if product.needsFinishTransaction {
                        SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
                    }
                    print("Purchase Success: \(product.productId)")
                case .error(let error):
                    switch error.code {
                    case .unknown:
                        print("Unknown error. Please contact support")
                    case .clientInvalid:
                        print("Not allowed to make the payment")
                    case .paymentCancelled:
                        print("Payment cancelled")
                    case .paymentInvalid:
                        print("The purchase identifier was invalid")
                    case .paymentNotAllowed:
                        print("The device is not allowed to make the payment")
                    case .storeProductNotAvailable:
                        print("The product is not available in the current storefront")
                    case .cloudServicePermissionDenied:
                        print("Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
                    case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed:
                        print("Could not connect to the network")
                    case .cloudServiceRevoked:
                        print("User has revoked permission to use this cloud service")
                    default:
                        print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be afraid of attackers – because it's only related to jailbroken devices and the only thing they can do is using your paid features for free. And no one can take the money. Everything is safe.

If you want just make IAP purchases you can use `SwiftyStoreKit`.

You can read [this article](https://blog.apphud.com/receipt-validation/) from our blog about receipt validation.